# 2011 Jeep grand Cherokee , 30,000 Klms calliper damaged new pads/rotors?

Tags: brakes, jeep, damage, brake-calipers

I had both front and back brakes replaced 9 months ago. Ive done 30,000 km since and I am being told the calliper failed, and burnt the new brakes out. Thee was no warning light or leaks. It'll cost another $800 to repair.

My question is, am I being misled? Now they are replacing the pads & rotor, but I have to pay for the callipers, tubing & 3 hours labor.

Could the new brakes done nine months ago have been faulty, or not installed correctly?

Comment: What are the symptoms? Were you having problems with your brakes, if so please describe them.

Comment: More information is needed.  What you describe is possible in theory.  But without some evidence nobody can really help.

Comment: Judging from what youre saying, it seems as if the caliper piston got stuck? Or possibly the slide pins seized (maybe they werent lubricated properly on initial install) so then one pad is wearing down faster than the other or wearing unevenly.

Frankly, im betting theyre just busting your balls. One caliper going bad wont make you replace like all of the rear brakes or all the way around, its usually just that one side especially if theyre brand new.